# Different file for each ip nginx

Tags: variables, nginx

So i am creating a server where every user has the same file but different content in it, for e.g. Lets say on the server there is a file like test.json and i want it to different between these two ip's, this ip 162.98.562.89 and this ip 189.56.895.23. I want the file to be different for each ip. How can i achieve this?
So in 189.56.895.23 the content of the file should be Test1
and for ip two; Test2
But i want the location of the file to be the same for both ips.. Please help me achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a handler function for your resource (e.g. myserver.com/test.json).

The handler

1. Identifies the IP address the request is coming from.
2. Makes the JSON for the IP address (the data per IP should be stored, maybe in a database)
3. Returns the JSON inside the HTTP response.

[X-FORWARDED-FOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) is the most common HTTP header field to include the original IP.

[Here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HeadersManagement#Get_a_header_value) are some examples how you can grab a HTTP header value in nginx.